# Using Twilio API resources within Twilio Functions

Tags: node.js, twilio

I've nearly finished my phone system with twilio and the final part is a voicemail playback. If the call fails or is declined, the calling party can leave a message and it saves to the twilio recordings. All server side code is done in Twilio Functions.

Now I want the end party to be able to check their voicemail by dialing an extension and playing back the saved messages. Everything up to the playing back of messages is done because I can't get the recording uri from a list of recordings.

Note NodeJS is not my strong suite.

I have tried playing back all recordings with:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
  let response = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  twilioClient.recordings.each(recording => response.play(recording.uri));

  callback(null, response);
}
```

But I don't the expected result (i.e. I get a 200 OK and the `<Response/>` xml). I have `Enable ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN` enabled in the functions configuration.

I feel like it has something to do with the callback and the request to the api being asynchronous but I couldn't find much information on the recordings docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/recording).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the documentation I was after in the automated docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.11.2/Twilio.Api.V2010.AccountContext.RecordingList.html).

```
client.recordings.each({
    callback: function (recording) {
        response.say('New Message');
        const recordingSid = recording.sid;
    },
    done: function () {
        callback(null, response);
    },
});
```